# How can I clone objects in JavaScript based on object's array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say I have an array of objects like this:

```js
let cars = [
  {
    "name": "Ford",
    "color": ["Blue", "Red"]
  },
  {
    "name": "Toyota",
    "color": ["Blue"]
  }
]
```

How can, without using a for loop, flatten the array out (flatMap perhaps?) so my array looks like this:

```js
let cars = [
  {
    "name": "Ford",
    "color": "Blue"
  },
  {
    "name": "Ford",
    "color": "Red"
  },
  {
    "name": "Toyota",
    "color": "Blue"
  }
]
```

The reason for not wanting to loop through is that my array is large and I have multiple arrays in the object that I wish to "explode" like this (so I end up iterating over the array 5 times).

Comment: simple reduce and foreach

Answer (score 1):

With [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) combination as the following:

```js
const cars = [{ "name": "Ford", "colors": ["Blue", "Red"] }, { "name": "Toyota", "colors": ["Blue"] }];

const result = cars.reduce((a, c) => {
  c.colors.forEach(e => {
    a.push({ name: c.name, colors: e });
  });
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

```js
let cars = [{
    "name": "Ford",
    "colors": ["Blue", "Red"]
  },
  {
    "name": "Toyota",
    "colors": ["Blue"]
  }
]

let result = cars.flatMap(e => {
  return e.colors.map((color)=>({name:e.name,color}))
});
console.log(result);
```

For multiple props *(just make sure each of them has **at least one** type and color)*

```js
let cars = [
  {
    "name": "Ford",
    "colors": ["Blue", "Red"],
    "type": ["4WD", "RWD"]
  },
  {
    "name": "Toyota",
    "colors": ["Blue"],
    "type":["TYPE"]
  }
]

function flatProps(arr,props){
  arr = [...arr]; //to perserve the original array
  props.forEach(prop => {
    arr = arr.flatMap(e => {
      return e[prop].map((value) => {
        let r = Object.assign({},e);
        r[prop] = value;
        return r;
      })
    });
  })
  return arr;
}

console.log(flatProps(cars,["colors","type"]));
```

Comment: That looks pretty neat!
Could this be expanded even further if the object has another array? E.g.
{ "name" : "Ford", "colors": ["Blue", "Red"], type: ["4WD", "RWD"] } should then map out to 4 objects to cover all variations

Comment: added a snippet for multiple props